# How to use Tensorflow Projection tool with TFlearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn, projector

I am new to Tensorflow and TFLearn and when I was following some tutorials I found the tool Projector https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=629s. I was trying to use it with TFLearn but I couldn't found any example in the internet and the documentation in the Tensorflow page is not the very intuitive https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/embedding. Can somebody help me with a proper example that integrate TFLearn and projector.